# Ceedling failing to mock header

Tags: c, cmock, ceedling

I am trying to mock a header which is included by a source file I am testing.

The header begins with the following:

```
#if defined(ICM42600)
#define ICM_WHOAMI ICM42600_WHOAMI
#elif defined(ICM42602)
#define ICM_WHOAMI ICM42602_WHOAMI
#elif defined(ICM42605)
#define ICM_WHOAMI ICM42605_WHOAMI
#elif defined(ICM42622)
#define ICM_WHOAMI ICM42622_WHOAMI
#elif defined(ICM42686)
#define ICM_WHOAMI ICM42686_WHOAMI
#elif defined(ICM42688)
#define ICM_WHOAMI ICM42688_WHOAMI
#elif defined(ICM42608)
#define ICM_WHOAMI ICM42608_WHOAMI
#elif defined(IIM42623)
#define ICM_WHOAMI IIM42623_WHOAMI
#elif defined(IIM42624)
#define ICM_WHOAMI IIM42624_WHOAMI
#elif defined(IIM42625)
#define ICM_WHOAMI IIM42625_WHOAMI
#elif defined(ICM40608)
#define ICM_WHOAMI ICM40608_WHOAMI
#else
#error "Please define which ICM variant is targeted. Possible values: ICM42600, ICM42602, ICM42605, ICM42686, ICM42688, ICM42622, ICM42608, ICM4068"
#endif
```

and I am attempting to mock it like so:

```
#define ICM42600 1
#include "mock_Icm426xxDefs.h"
```

However, I keep getting the following error when trying to run ceedling tests:

```
----------------------------
Generating include list for Icm426xxDefs.h...
build/temp/_Icm426xxDefs.h:74:2: error: #error "Please define which ICM variant is targeted. Possible values: ICM42600, ICM42602, ICM42605, ICM42686, ICM42688, ICM42622, ICM42608, ICM4068"
 #error "Please define which ICM variant is targeted. Possible values: ICM42600, ICM42602, ICM42605, ICM42686, ICM42688, ICM42622, ICM42608, ICM4068"
  ^~~~~
```

I have no idea how to deal with this. I was under the impression that ceedling would automatically mock headers, and there's no error saying what I can do to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

The output of the `#error` message means that none of the (other) definitions of `ICM_WHOAMI` was used.

Why the `#define` before the `#include` was not seen would require other info that you have not provided

Answer (score 0):

I had also problems with defines that were not passed to included files.
Try to pass the define with option -D directly to the compiler and linker by adding
them to the project.yml:

:flags:
:test:
:compile:
:*:
- -D ICM42600
:link:
:*:
- -D ICM42600